# Extract values from json string javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a multiselect element from select2 to enter multiple "tags". When I want to get the value from the element I get something like this (for tag1 en tag2 which I entered in the box):

```
[{"id":"tag1","text":"tag1"},{"id":"tag2","text":"tag2"}]
```

How do I get the result from text in an array something like this:

```
[0] = "tag1"
[1] = "tag2"
```

And how do I reverse this process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simple iteration.

```
var obj = [{"id":"tag1","text":"tag1"},{"id":"tag2","text":"tag2"}] ;

for (var i =0; i< obj.length ;i++) {
   console.log(obj[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another approach

```
[{"id":"tag1","text":"tag1"},{"id":"tag2","text":"tag2"}].map(function(el) {
 return el.id;
});
```

Comment: +1 Using `map()`, nice approach which returns those id to an array.

Comment: Sure is, if it's supported ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":"tag1","text":"tag1"},{"id":"tag2","text":"tag2"}] ');
data[0].id
data[1].id
```

Try this will help you

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what OP is asking for. OP needed a programmatic solution, not a direct query. This wouldn't work in 1000 objects array.