# json stringify result get value on specific key

Tags: javascript, json, string

```
[{"displayorder":"1","menuname":"DashBoard","menuid":"5","menuurl":"dashboard.php"},{"displayorder":"3","menuname":"Accounting Module","menuid":"3","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"4","menuname":"My Profile","menuid":"4","menuurl":"myprofile.php"},{"displayorder":"6","menuname":"HR Module","menuid":"2","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"9","menuname":"Administrator","menuid":"1","menuurl":""}]
```

I have here a stringfy json i want to know how to get a value of all the menuname in this json object any idea appreciated

`UPDATE:`
I tried this one 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142454/extract-values-from-json-string-javascript) but I get undefined in console

`UPDATE`

```
[{"displayorder":"1","menuname":"Menu Management","menuid":"1","submenuurl":"","parentid":"1"},{"displayorder":"1","menuname":"hr sub menu","menuid":"7","submenuurl":"error.php","parentid":"2"},{"displayorder":"2","menuname":"Role Management","menuid":"2","submenuurl":"","parentid":"1"},{"displayorder":"2","menuname":"menu 2 management2","menuid":"8","submenuurl":"","parentid":"2"},{"displayorder":"3","menuname":"hrsubmenu","menuid":"3","submenuurl":"contactus.php","parentid":"2"},{"displayorder":"3","menuname":"submenuaccounting","menuid":"4","submenuurl":"imagegallery.php","parentid":"3"}];
```

how to get all all details in the second json with `parentid` depending on above `menuid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/0866pay3/

```
var json = [{"displayorder":"1","menuname":"DashBoard","menuid":"5","menuurl":"dashboard.php"},{"displayorder":"3","menuname":"Accounting Module","menuid":"3","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"4","menuname":"My Profile","menuid":"4","menuurl":"myprofile.php"},{"displayorder":"6","menuname":"HR Module","menuid":"2","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"9","menuname":"Administrator","menuid":"1","menuurl":""}];

    
json.forEach(function(el, idx){
    console.log(el.menuname);
});
```

#### Documentation Update

If you check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you'll see the following:

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element index
> - the array being traversed

So, `idx` is just a common way of representing the element index. You can call this whatever you'd like - `theIndex`, `myRandomName`, etc.

Comment: i need 8 mins to tick the answer

Comment: what is idx please explain

Comment: @HogRider See my Documentation Update on the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myjson = [{"displayorder":"1","menuname":"DashBoard","menuid":"5","menuurl":"dashboard.php"},{"displayorder":"3","menuname":"Accounting Module","menuid":"3","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"4","menuname":"My Profile","menuid":"4","menuurl":"myprofile.php"},{"displayorder":"6","menuname":"HR Module","menuid":"2","menuurl":""},{"displayorder":"9","menuname":"Administrator","menuid":"1","menuurl":""}]; 


var menu_names = []; 

for (var x = 0 ; x < myjson.length; x++){
    if(myjson[x].hasOwnProperty('menuname')){
        // do something usefull here 
        console.log(myjson[x]['menuname']);
        // add value to new array 
        menu_names.push(myjson[x]['menuname'])
    }
}

console.log(menu_names);
```